# Return all occurrences of a string

Tags: regex, macos, cocoa, swift

I'm trying to figure out how to get each occurrence of a string from a much bigger string.

**Example of larger string:**

```
"xmp_id": 3243041, "certified": 1,"xmp_id": 3243042, "certified":
 1,"xmp_id": 3243043, "certified": 1,"xmp_id": 3243044, "certified":
 1,"xmp_id":     3243045, "certified": 1,"xmp_id": 3243046, "certified": 
1,"xmp_id": 3243047,     "certified": 1,"xmp_id": 3243048, "certified": 
1,"xmp_id": 3243049, "certified":     1,"xmp_id": 3243050, "certified":
 1,"xmp_id": 3243051, "certified": 1,"xmp_id":     3243052, "certified": 1,
```

In VB.Net i would use something like this to get the value of each "xmp_id":

```
Dim inputString As String = RichTextBox1.Text
Dim pattern As String = "(?<=\<b1\>).+?(?=\<\/b1\>)"
Dim col As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(inputString, pattern)
For Each match As Match In col
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups(1).Value)
Next
```

I have searched everywhere and have not been able to find anything equivalent to the VB.Net code. I'd like to get the strings between **"xmp_ID":** and **, "certified":** Anyone have any ideas how to go about this in Swift?

Comment: i thin this `(?<=\"xmp_ID\":\s+).*?(?=,\s+\"certified\":)` may work.

Comment: How would i go about looping this to get all occurrences? I will also check this to see if it finds one at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift doesn't have its own regular expression support, but you can use Foundation's `NSRegularExpression` class.  It produces `NSTextCheckingResult` objects.  It's something of a pain to use Swift's `String` type with `NSRegularExpression` and `NSTextCheckingResult`, so first cast your input string to `NSString`.

```
let text = "\"xmp_id\": 3243041, \"certified\": 1,\"xmp_id\": 3243042, \"certified\": 1,\"xmp_id\": 3243043, \"certified\": 1,\"xmp_id\": 3243044, \"certified\": 1,\"xmp_id\":     3243045, \"certified\": 1,\"xmp_id\": 3243046, \"certified\": 1,\"xmp_id\": 3243047,     \"certified\": 1,\"xmp_id\": 3243048, \"certified\": 1,\"xmp_id\": 3243049, \"certified\":     1,\"xmp_id\": 3243050, \"certified\": 1,\"xmp_id\": 3243051, \"certified\": 1,\"xmp_id\":     3243052, \"certified\": 1," as NSString

let rx = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\"xmp_id\": ([0-9]+)", options: nil, error: nil)!
let range = NSMakeRange(0, text.length)
let matches = rx.matchesInString(text, options: nil, range: range)
for matchObject in matches {
    let match = matchObject as NSTextCheckingResult
    let range = match.rangeAtIndex(1)
    let value = text.substringWithRange(range)
    println(value)
}
```